# Struts2 custom display:tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, displaytag

I have used **display:table** in my JSP page to display the data from Struts2 Action class

```
<display:table name="Clients" class="table table-condensed table-hover" requestURI="" id="ClientList" export="true" pagesize="5">
        <display:column property="clientKey" sortable="true" href="editMClient" media="html"
            paramId="clientKey" paramProperty="clientKey" titleKey="mClient.clientKey"/>
        <display:column property="clientKey" media="csv excel xml pdf" titleKey="mClient.clientKey"/>
        <display:column property="MClientcol" sortable="true" titleKey="mClient.MClientcol"/>
        <display:column property="clientName" sortable="true" titleKey="mClient.clientName"/>

    <%--Many columns --%>

 </display:table>
```

And I am geting output like this.

[image]

I want to change the style. I mean, I don't want to display page numbers, I just want to display previous and next only, that too with images (like in GMail).

In the page, I given page size to 5. I want to display a select box displaying 10,20,30 options so that, when user selects a number, that number of rows show on the page. (Like in **JQGrid**, but I waant to use display:table).

I also don't want to display export link for XML.

How can I achieve these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at configuration file `displaytag.properties`. You can set `paging.banner.full` and others (paging.banner.*) how to display pages.
http://www.displaytag.org/10/configuration.html